# NDK AAsset_read(): Recommended buffer size?

Tags: android-ndk, android-assets

Just wondering what's optimal here, as no suggestions are made in the [NDK docs](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___asset.html). I'm fairly sure that although `bufSize` is of type `size_t`, specifying `SIZE_MAX` might not be a wise choice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your file is *small* (That's subjective but for me small is under 512kb) what you can do is:

```
AAsset* file = AAssetManager_open(assetManager, "your/file.ext", AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
size_t fileLength = AAsset_getLength(file);
char* fileContent = new char[fileLength];
AAsset_read(file, fileContent, fileLength);
```

It can actually work for file a lot larger until your memory allocation fail.

If you plan on loading huge file then I would read by chunck of 512kb but again, that's subjective, there is no hard limit (Until the memory allocation fail)

Comment: Yes, it's a bit vague... 512kb is the L2 cache size on my old Galaxy S test phone and probably other devices of that era - Gingerbread, which is mine and many other people's minimum API level, so that figure makes sense. If we knew more about native calls being made under the hood of `AAsset_read`, that might also help in arriving at a figure. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have knowledge of the code behind that function, but I've dealt with it a lot in the last years, and I ended up with 512kb as my chunck size because:
   [1]: After tests it works good when you load multiple file at a time in various thread (tested on many device with android 4.+)
  [2]: It doesn't fill the L2 cache on many devices (if you read 2-3 or more file in various thread, you would prefer (ideally) all the chunks to stay in cache)

Comment: @Sistr how do i get assetManager object

Comment: Sry for the late reply @SumitKumarSaha. If you use the native activity it's part of the C++ api of the native activity.
If you are using a java activity. just send it to your C++ through jni (as a jobject) and then call:

    AAssetManager_fromJava(env, java_jobject_of_your_asset_manager);